# How to enable JMX in wildfly running in windows server 2016

Tags: wildfly, jmx, jconsole, jvisualvm, jmc

I'm running wildfly in windows server. Need to setup JMX to monitor remotely

I have tried adding JMX settings in standalone.conf.bat file and opened firewall port, but still not able to monitor using jconsole

**Environment:**

- Wildfly 23
- Redhat 1.8.275
- Windows Server 2016

Things i tried:

Added the following settings in standalone.conf.bat file in bin folder

set "JAVA_OPTS=-Xms64M -Xmx512M -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m" set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=$JBOSS_MODULES_SYSTEM_PKGS -Djava.awt.headless=true" set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman,org.jboss.logmanager" set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9010" set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xbootclasspath/p:<JBOSS_HOME>\wildfly-23.0.1.Final\modules\system\layers\base\org\jboss\logmanager\main\jboss-logmanager-2.1.18.Final.jar -Xbootclasspath/p:<JBOSS_HOME>\wildfly-23.0.1.Final\modules\system\layers\base\org\wildfly\common\main\wildfly-common-1.5.4.Final .jar" set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"

Service started without errors and was able to monitor using jconsole as localhost , but not from remote

Port was exposed in firewall settings though

Clarification Needed

Do i need to disable default management port 9990 in standalone .xml file for this to work

but if thats the case i'm able to monitor using the jmx port in local

Any help or suggestions please

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked for me with below settings at last. I was missing the below property
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=<port#>

**Complete Property looks like this**

set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=<port#>-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=<port#>
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"

Apart from this i setup the SSL for the wildfly

It worked for me

Thanks all